# I'm using SOAPUI sending SOAP Envelope to a third party SOAP service. In response to that I'm getting following execption,

Tags: soap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fUFn.png)    
       
       
          
             
             123456748
             
             EN
             
             ?

Can anybody help me dig out the cause of this exception? I think that exception is occuring on client side.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you should post request/response and [link for WSDL](https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/assets/wsdl/developers/customerinfo.wsdl) in your question and not only image.

Your request is not valid (right mouse button > validate or alt + v). Platform-id has to be filled or whole element has to be omitted.

Next problem is that there is API key for this service and you, probably, do not have set authorization for your request, [see official information](https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/soap/fundamentals.jsf).